# How can I send a mail in linux shell script, using mail, but also awk?

Tags: linux, shell

What I really want is, I have a file: `example.txt`
The file is structured this way: `FirstName LastName UserID Grade`

I have two options: If the Grade is greater than 5 I want a mail to the user via [UserID]:

```
Dear [FirstName] [LastName]!
On this subject, your grade is [Grade]!
```

The second option is: If the [Grade] is less than 5 I want a mail to the user via [UserID]:

```
Dear [FirstName] [LastName]!
On this subject, your grade was less than 5!
```

Using `awk'{print $1}'` etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks like homework assignment. Please share what you have tried so far ?  For filtering records based on `Grade` you can used `$NF >5` in awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following script file :

```
#!/bin/bash
your_grade_files="/path_to_file.txt"

while read p; do

  FirstName=$(echo $p | awk -F' ' '{print $1}')
  LastName=$(echo $p | awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
  UserID=$(echo $p | awk -F' ' '{print $3}')
  Grade=$(echo $p | awk -F' ' '{print $4}')  

    if [ "$Grade" -gt 5 ]
    then
        mail -s "Enter your subject here" $UserID <<< "Dear $FirstName $LastName! On this subject, your grade is [ $Grade ] "
    else
        mail -s "Enter your subject here" $UserID <<< "Dear $FirstName $LastName! On this subject, your grade was less than 5!"
    fi
done < $your_grade_files
```

Comment: I don't understand why is giving me a syntax error near fi

Comment: Thank you for your time and help sir! I managed to do my homework!

Comment: Good job. I edited the solution, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question , You ll need to read the contents of the file iteratively

As you parse the contents line by line you can apply the mail to be triggered , based on the Grade value

```
while read line; do    
    grade = $(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $4}')
    userid = $(echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $3}')
    if [[ $grade -gt 5]] then
       sendMail $userid $grade
done < file.txt

func sendMail(){
   userid = $1 
   grade = $2
   MESSAGE="[$] : Your Grade -- $2"
   SUBJECT="SOME SUBJECT"
   TOADDR="u@u.com"
   FROM="DONOTREPLY"

    echo $MESSAGE | mail  -s "$SUBJECT" $TOADDR -f $FROM
}
```

You can further modify the code snippet based on your requirement

Comment: I want to send mail in both cases

Comment: to send mail in both cases you ll need to add another condition for your grade as described in the solution by Youssef. The snippet I provided is a bare bone version , u ll need to modify it